# In POSIX sh, how to preserve variables set in a 'while read' loop when the input is continuous (event watcher)?

Tags: shell, scope, event-handling, posix, subshell

If you don't need to set global variables, or are willing to use named pipes, you can use:

```
$NAMED_PIPE="/tmp/mypipe"
mkfifo $NAMED_PIPE

command | # piped into while read, command can be an event watcher
    while read -r foo bar; do
        MY_VAR="$foo"
        echo "$MY_VAR" # This works
        echo "MY_VAR" > "$NAMED_PIPE" &
    done

echo "$MY_VAR" # This doesn't work
cat "$NAMED_PIPE" # This works
```

If you need to set global variables, you can use the following in bash:

```
while read -r foo bar; do
    MY_VAR="$foo"
    echo "$MY_VAR" # This works
done < <(command) # command can be an event watcher

echo "$MY_VAR" # This works
```

In POSIX sh, you can do the following, but it doesn't work with continuous input (seems to just hang):

```
while read -r foo bar; do
    MY_VAR="$foo"
    echo "$MY_VAR" # Works as long as command doesn't produce continuous output
done <<-EOF
$(command) 
EOF

echo "$MY_VAR" # Works as long as command doesn't produce continuous output
```

Is there a solid way to parse an event watcher (e.g. xev, xprop -spy) in POSIX sh and be able to set global variables? Named pipes seem difficult to use portably and safely.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without named pipes (or some eval hack, which is widely frowned upon for good reasons). Besides all POSIX-compliant systems implement them, what makes you think that *[n]amed pipes seem difficult to use portably and safely.*?

Comment: I've read that mktemp isn't specified by POSIX, and that signal handling (to clean up in case of kill/hang) can also be problematic, so I don't know what method to use that I can feel confident in.

Comment: meta comment : Note the low number of watchers for most of your tags. Tags on S.O. are best used to attract watchers of specific topics. You may hate to use `[bash]` but you'll get 2X eyes on your Q.  `bash` is now a reasonable assumption to be available (IMO). Generally speaking, this level of discussion/topic is pretty rare here. Maybe search archives of comp.unix.shell (where I do remember seeing such discussions) will get you some more ideas. And consider using a language that has fewer issues with buffering. `gawk` and `perl` are generally available everywhere. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The named pipe is the solution, but you are using it in the wrong place.

```
NAMED_PIPE="/tmp/mypipe"
mkfifo "$NAMED_PIPE"

command > "$NAMED_PIPE" &

while read -r foo bar; do
    MY_VAR="$foo"
    echo "$MY_VAR"
done < "$NAMED_PIPE"

echo "$MY_VAR"
```